# Why does Oracle indicate my table is using so little space?

Tags: oracle

I'm running Oracle 11g.  I have a table with two BLOB columns.  I inserted 10,000 rows into the table, and each column contained a byte array of size 10289.

As you can see, there are 10,000 rows in the table and each column has 10,289 bytes in it:

```
SQL> select count(*) from MYUSER.MYTABLE;

  COUNT(*)
----------
     10000

SQL> select min(length(COL1)), min(length(COL2)) from MYUSER.MYTABLE;

MIN(LENGTH(COL1))      MIN(LENGTH(COL2))
-----------------      -----------------
            10289                  10289
```

Therefore the table should be using up at least 205MB of space (10289 bytes * 2 * 10000).

But I used the query given [here](https://serverfault.com/a/132625/180506) to find out how much space the table is using, and I got the following:

```
SQL> SELECT SUM(bytes), SUM(bytes)/1024/1024 MB FROM dba_extents WHERE owner = 'MYUSER' AND segment_name = 'MYTABLE';

SUM(BYTES)         MB
---------- ----------
   2097152          2
```

Why does it say the table is using up just 2 MB when it should be using up 250 MB?

The byte arrays I'm inserting are compressed data, so Oracle couldn't possibly be compressing that data any further.

Comment: LOBs are stored out of row if they're bigger than 4k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table's segment is only 2 MB.  The rest of the data is stored in the LOB segments which are physically separate from the table segment.

```
SELECT column_name, segment_name
  FROM dba_lobs
 WHERE owner = 'MYUSER'
   AND table_name = 'MYTABLE'
```

should show you that there are two LOB segments associated with the table.  You can then query `dba_segments` to get the size of those segments

```
SELECT sum(bytes)/1024/1024 mb
  FROM dba_segments
 WHERE owner = 'MYUSER'
   AND segment_name IN (SELECT segment_name
                          FROM dba_lobs
                         WHERE owner = 'MYUSER'
                           AND table_name = 'MYTABLE')
```